# Portal 2 - What do the turrets sing in the end

Tags: portal-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Portal 2's Turret Symphony Song and Lyrics?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/portal-2s-turret-symphony-song-and-lyrics)

When the turrets sing their song while you are riding the lift to the surface, it sounds a lot like real words. Do they sing a real, existing song / opera piece, or a song created specifically for this occasion, or just sounds created to give the impression of a real song?

Comment: See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/portal-2s-turret-symphony-song-and-lyrics

Comment: Whoops, didn't see that one before posting. Thanks for pointing it out. Cheers!