# What are the lyrics to the song PotatOS Lament on Volume 2 of the Portal 2 Soundtrack?

Tags: portal-2

What are the lyrics to the song "PotatOS Lament" on Volume 2 of the Portal 2 soundtrack? It doesn't sound like English (though some parts do sound like the word "potatoes").

Is it another language? Or just gibberish?

Comment: I don't think it's any language in particular

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Potato Lacrimosa (Weeping Potato)

Potato Po Uota (Power Potato Vows)

Diva Me A Atra Anima Evicta (My soul won over by the black goddess)

Diu E Me A Atra A Mei A Adiu (Me from my long blackout, from any aid)

Tristi Anima Evicta (Sadness won over my soul)

Tristi Demu Notu (Sadness at last known)

Do Mo Nata Anima Evicta (I give only the soul born the right to win)

Dega Mi Atra Ala Te Teme Cha (You yourself live because of the black wing of my charity)

Answer (score 9):

All signs point to the actual lyrics being a mixture of gibberish and bad Italian/Latin. In reponse to a question about the Turret Song on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/iur9l/glados_responds_to_rgamings_questions/), Ellen McLain answered as follows:

> The composer, Mike Morasky was the driving force behind the Turret Opera. He wrote all the music. He requested that I use my legit voice (operatic sound) on some of the takes. He chose the takes to use. He asked me to make up some words. So I did so in my bad Italian.

This most likely carried over to the PotatOS Lament song, as further strengthened by a thread on the [Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=23740276&postcount=29), pointing to an appearance of Ellen McLain at Anime Midwest 2011 of which a Youtube video is included in the post. During the panel the PotatOS Lament song is specifically mentioned, however Ellen names it "GLaDOS Lament", of which the following is said:

> She then goes on to say she made up words to it using her "bad High School Latin" (lol) which means the song is both Latin AND gibberish.

So there we have it! Bad Latin/Italian and gibberish.

Comment: The closest I've seen to a translation was in that [Steam thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1965781&page=2): `"Master you are made blessed, cave no surrender" and then possibly "computer" at the end. (Dominus tu no bebula, cave dedo nulla. caculo)`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it has anything to do with the ending turret song 'Cara Mia'.
I think it sounds like she's singing lyrics to Vitrification Order on the Second Volume. I'll let you determine if that's the song she's singing. You can hear it near the end of the song for sure, but you need to really listen for it.

As for the lyrics, she's probably singing in Italian... Still trying to get the lyrics myself if it is indeed in Italian.

But yeah, definitely listen to Vitrification Order and tell me that it doesn't sound like PotatOS Lament.

But, this might also help. I can hear 'lacrimosa' at the beginning of the Lament. 'Potato Lacrimosa' to be exact. Translate it, you get 'Crying or Tearful Potato". I can make out other words too. Sounds a lot like Mozart's piece Lacrimosa - Requiem. [Here's the Lyrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacrimosa_%28Requiem%29).

```
Lacrimosa dies illa
Qua resurget ex favilla
Judicandus homo reus.
Huic ergo parce, Deus:
Pie Jesu Domine,
Dona eis requiem. Amen.

English translation

Tearful will be that day
on which from the ashes will rise
the guilty man for judgment.
So have mercy, O Lord, on this man.
Compassionate Lord Jesus,
grant them rest. Amen.
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it might be a remix of [this song](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/portal-2s-turret-symphony-song-and-lyrics), though the words have been garbled to be less intelligible.

Comment: Sounds plausible, I'll mark this as accepted unless I get a better/certain answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's Latin, judging by the occasional "Dominus" (meaning God) I can understand.